# RSA encryption not working

Tags: encryption, rsa

I'm trying to implement a simple version of RSA encryption for an assignment I have to do for school.

The thing is I must be doing something wrong. I chose the prime numbers 17 and 29 so n = 493
I chose 491 to be my encryption key and therefore 246 is the decryption key. But when I start trying to encrypt and decrypt a message (I have ASCII code and I encode character by character in their decimal value) I don't get the same message when decrypting.

For example when I try with the letter "L" L=76
So I do x=76^491 (mod 493) and the result is 359
But when I do x=359^246 (mod 493) I get 13 as a result, which is not the 76 I needed.

What is it I'm doing wrong here? Because I read a lot about RSA and it should be working but it's not so I must have done something wrong.

Thank you for your time and I'd really appreciate it if I got an answer soon. The assignment is due next Monday.

Comment: Unless you post the relevant code I don't think anyone is going to be able to help you with this.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have calculated the private exponent incorrectly. It should be 323, not 246.

The private exponent is the inverse of the public exponent modulo Phi(N) = (p-1)(q-1), whereas you appear to have calculated the inverse modulo N.

Comment: Oh that seems to be the problem. Thank you very much. I should've realized that. But thanks